# Could someone help identify these two shrubs?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I am doing an ecology project for biology and we have to identify these plants (genus and species). We're having a bit of trouble, so any help is greatly appreciated!
[image]

and the second plant:
[image]

Comment: how about some clues as to where these plants are growing. Are they wild or cultivated?  (by the way I never seen a site that sets so many cookies as photobucket)

Answer (score 3):

The first is a holly, but I am not sure about the second.

Answer (score 0):

Top one is an evergreen oak, Quercus ilex? The holly shaped leaves give it away- just because it has holly like leaves doesn't make it a holly! I can think of 4 or 5 examples that are not hollies! As for the second- never seen that in old blighty? haven't a clue! sorry- hope the top one helps.